# CCAvenue Return To Merchant Page

Tags: android, ccavenue

I am newbie to CCAvenue Payment gateway. While I tried to execute Seamless app which is integrated into my app shows the following. Here is a button `"Return to Merchant Site"` (SCREEN 1). While I click, it shows next screen (SCREEN 2).

**I need to return back to my app while the successive transaction. How to do these things? Please help me.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Recently i am also facing this issue ,can you please check your `Transaction URL` domain name "https://`secure.ccavenue.com`/transaction/initTrans" or "https://`secure.ccavenue.ae`/transaction/initTrans"

hope it would be working fine